Ambari agent is not able to connect to ambari server
I have configure the ambari server and ambari agent. Whan ambari agent is trying to connect to server, call is getting failed because its calling http://localhost:8080/resources/host_scripts.
I have add fully.qualified.domain.name in ini file in ambari agent.
WARNING 2024-08-01 07:18:58,723 FileCache.py:204 - Error occurred during cache update. Error tolerate setting is set to true, so ignoring this error and continuing with current cache. Error details: Can not download file from url http://localhost:8080/resources/host_scripts/.hash : <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>

